# Workplace behavior issue with colleague!

Tags: human-resources

I was hired 2 years ago in a small org by sales team, the sales sr admin was to be a mentor to prepare me about organization, projects, technical discussion. He used to schedule meetings in conference rooms one on one and try to accidentally touch hand or move closer I would immediately distance away but in 1 or 2 meetings, I understood his inappropriate behavior I was very strict seriously had to draw a line, reduce talk about work, started focus to prove my technical skill to sr.boss but realize that this mentor and sr. Boss is a team and he doesn't know that mentor behaved like that with new hire.

Another point is this mentor don't have much technical skills even his sr.boss doesn't understand technical stuff so they support each other bcoz they noticed that I had improved my technical knowledge the mentor wouldn't involve me to interact with the  business teams or other technical teams and if at all someone assign me task directly without knowing him though I submit task on time he says even a layman can't understand this what you have done and he disrespects me all the time.

Upon seeing my proven technical skills he started to invite me for lunch to come alone but I turned it down immediately. This used to happen precovid, and then I'm glad this pandemic made me to work remote so that I wouldn't see him face to face.

How should I get rid of such toxic people?
Whom should I complain all this?

Now I have new manager for both me and sr,admin guy. Should I tell him my story is it appropriate or should I complain to HR as this is act of abuse I cant handle this anymore. I just cry and pray to God to save me every time he behaved like that

Our new manager seems to be humble and kind, before the transfer to the team that mentor guy did mention he doesn't like the collaboration with bigger leadership team as these guys are very much technically skilled. I appreciate the fact God has answered my prayers sending this new management. But I don't know if I could say all this to manager what impression does it make about our small org employees or further communication with me I don't want to get disturbed. The previous 2 boses  were  supporting this mentor guy as they weren't much technology skilled together.

I understand everyone has family and working hard in careers I don't want to destroy that
But he is destroying my peace of mind with his toxic behavior

What shall I do? Is being a woman wrong?
Or improving my technical skills to prove myself is wrong?

I'm working hard for the bread and butter to my family and to be respectful in workplace and to improve my technical knowledge so that I can be expertise in implementing task in my field
I want to be happy and feel safe working in office but I rather feel happy working at home much better, more productive, more confidence, more efficient.

But I have to return to work post March I don't want to sit behind that mentor guy's  cube. I don't want to work with him. He is on my team I cant get rid of him  but I hate to be in office with his petty politics.
I more calm, focused on working remote atleast I don't get much harassed.

I also delivered my baby in pandemic with my family, when every collegue is Congratulating before I take off maternity leave this mentor guy called to congratulate but said looks like your good at getting babies, why don't you go for 3rd baby? Well, You can enjoy the leave as well !!! I said to myself Is maternal leave an enjoyable ride for any mom? Am I going on a vacation? I'm shocked and hang up the call. Is this way any one speak to congratulate professionally?

Even working remote, in meetings where my new manager is not involved he insults me that layman statement I mentioned above he did that in today's meeting  I was literally in tears that's the reason I decided to get help from you all but being face to face with him is much worse he observes me too much, micro manage every task I work though he is not my boss just another employee like me

After reading all this you can realize  these are the painful situations that hit me hard and stuck in my mind, this mentor guy always finds an opportunity whenever he can to bug others, I don't understand what happiness he get to make others cry. This is like endless

I apologize for the very long text. Thank you so much for taking time to read patiently and Thanks to workplace site admins for allowing space to vent off my grief and stress

Comment: Please add some formatting. Wall of text not read.

Comment: And some punctuation, please

Comment: The problem doesn't exist right now since you're working remotely?

Comment: While the seniors behaviour is completely inacceptable as well as inappropriat and warrants for drastic and immediate actions, comparing flirtous behaviour and dinner-invites with torture (_'..I  cant handle this or bear any more torture'_) is a bit much IMO.. If you don't want to work with him, ask for a tranferral or get him out of his chair via a formal complaint adressed at his manager or even escalate to HR..

Comment: Can i talk to HR directly all this. Thanks for the update I will call the HR and manager and inform everything

Comment: *Is being a woman wrong? Or improving my technical skills to prove myself is wrong?* No no no. Don't think like that. You are not in the wrong here. He is. So don't think like that. Also, for people to provide better answers, it would help to know where you are located. Unfortunately culture plays a role in how you can handle this and what real options you have to improve the situation.

Comment: Welcome new user.  I urge you to "edit" the question and just make it shorter.  To get more answers!

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to read all of it but from what I got is you have a mentor person at the office and this person is making comments about your personal life or appearance.

Did you talk to your manager that you do not feel comfortable with the new mentor because of his inappropriate comments? Just say while he doesn't say or do anything specific, give the examples you gave here. Perhaps your manager can get you a new mentor and perhaps get you a new seating arrangement. Don't just tell your manager you don't like him, specifically explain situations that brought on your feelings.

Just remember the other guy may be forthcoming to the manager and say he said the things. However, most likely he will say he never said those things and that he doesn't understand where this is coming from. It'll be your words against his but at the same time, if you tell your manager, you at least have the upper hand for any sort of future incidence where you have hard proof. Hard proof will require either an email or situation that cannot be disputed by anyone. If you already have that, definitely have it in your hands when you go speak to your manger.

Just call your manager up, tell them you'd like to speak to them for about half an hour to discuss some personal issues you have at the office and bring any sort of proof you have. Even if you don't have hard proof, still bring up those events. Just always remember to be factual and never add your personal feelings or how others might feel. Just start off the example situation like, "We were at the maternity party and after everyone left the room, the mentor came to me and said I am good at making babies and should go for 3 so I can take time off. I was shocked and did not know what to say." Don't add anything else to that. Adding emotional elements to your story could derail your objective of having this person stop and go away because it will be hard to prove the emotional state or what people were thinking at the time.